# R markdown toc float not displaying

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, tableofcontents

I am using this yaml header

```
title: "Assembly with Shasta"
output:
  html_document:
    code_folding: "hide"
    number_sections: TRUE
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: true
      smooth_scroll: false
    theme: flatly
```

For some reason, this doesn't work, when knitting I get a collapsed grey bar where the toc should be. More strangely, the exact same yaml in other documents works perfectly fine. What inside the document are known causes for failure to knit a toc? As far as I could see, my document is perfectly "ok".

Any suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: It's hard to say without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If there are no headers `## ` in the document then the TOC would be empty.